# Is it possible to get the 2D coordinates of a vector after it has been rendered in Three.js

Tags: three.js

for instance, if I have a line geometry composed of points. Is it possible for me to get the 2D coordinates of the points after it has been rendered?

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter whether your 3D object has been rendered or not. You extract vertex position data in world space always in the same way:

```js
const geometry = line.geometry;
const positionAttribute = geometry.getAttribute( 'position' );

const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
vertex.fromBufferAttribute( positionAttribute, index );

// world space

line.localToWorld( vertex ); 

// NDC space

vertex.project( camera );

// 2D screen space

const x = ( vertex.x + 1 ) * width / 2;
const y = - ( vertex.y - 1 ) * height / 2;
```

`index` represents the vertex index in the vertex position buffer. `width` and `height` represent the dimensions of the canvas

Comment: Thanks for answering. I should have actually framed my question better. I am looking for the X and Y coordinates as they appear on the screen after being projected, not their world space coordinates.

Comment: Updated the code of the answer.